# jQuery html attribute not working in IE

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am using country and state dropdowns in my form. Whenever the user selects the country in the dropdown, the respective states of the country will populate in the states dropdown.  I am populating the states in the dropdown using AJAX call. The problem is that the states get populated in Mozilla but it doesn't work in IE. I guess there is some problem in jQuery while loading the states in the states dropdown. The jQuery code i am using is

```
$('select#edit-country').change(function(e) {

    $.getJSON("loadContactUsStates",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
        var options = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) { 
            options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';

        }

    <!-----I guess the problem is with the below line------------------>
       $("select#edit-state").html(options);

    })//end json

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does IE not add <option> to my dropDown?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607633/why-does-ie-not-add-option-to-my-dropdown)

Answer (score 12):

Try using **append** instead of the **html** method as detailed in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery).

**edit**

Actually, I've just run into this problem myself. For me the answer was to call [empty](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) first, then [append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) which has the same effect (I think?) as using the html method.

Comment: It should, but see my post regarding 1.4.2 breakage.

Answer (score 10):

Also (in my case) check if you have valid html, I had mismatched tags, and it worked in firefox and didn't in IE(6-8)

Comment: I had the same problem, strange that unclosed tag would make IE ignore all the content.

Comment: Same here... I had a type in one of my <option> tags and it caused me about 2 hours of misery.

Answer (score 9):

add to .ajax options

cache: false,

Answer (score 4):

**This is what worked for me: (I tested on IE7 - IE9, and Chrome)**

**It looks like the trick for IE is to use a DIV wrapper**

**Original html:**

```
<div  id="dynamicMenu"></div>
```

**jQuery script:**

```
$.ajax({

            url: "/myapp/myajaxUrl.jsp",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            async: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#dynamicMenu").html(msg);
            });
```

**Where msg is something like:**

```
<TABLE>
<TBODY>
 <TR>
  <TD><LABEL for="dropdown1">OS type:</LABEL></TD>
  <TD>
   <SELECT id="dropdown1">
    <OPTION selected value="">Select OS</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="WIN">Windoze</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="UX">Unix</OPTION>
    <OPTION value="LX">Linux</OPTION>
   </SELECT>
  </TD>
 </TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

**I tried .empty() .html() to no avail but the above worked great!**

Answer (score 4):

The following method solved the problem for me:

```
$('Element ID OR Class').empty().html(string);
```

First use `empty()` & then set html using `html()`

Comment: Yep worked for me as well. the only issue was with ie and this method resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are parsing xml using jquery, and you need html() in IE, try this:

var content = ($.browser.msie) ? $(this).context.xml : $(this).html();

This solved my problem. I hope it will help someone too.

Greetings.

Answer (score 3):

After hours of frustration I realized that IE does not support jquery attribute functions for html5 elements other than div. I was trying to do this:

```
success: function (response, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    $response = $(response.replace(/\t/g, " "));
    $responseHTML = $response.find("#pageContainer").html();
    $container.html($responseHTML);
```

For this element:

```
<nav id="pageContainer" class="content">
</nav>
```

By changing it to this it solved the problem:

```
<nav>
    <div id="pageContainer" class="content">
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue and none of the suggested fixes helped. Turns out tab characters in the passed string were the cause. As soon as I removed all of them, both html() and append() worked just fine. Guess no formatted strings for IE.. hmpf.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after receiving an AJAX HTML-Request with the function **jQuery.ajax()** and then trying to parse the result with **jQuery( html_result_data )**. The solution was to strip the header and all tabs and "returns" in the html_result_data like this:

```
success: function( data ) {
   // God this is ugly
   data = data.split("<body>")[1].split("</body>")[0];
   data = data.split("\t").join("").split("\r").join("").split("\n").join("");                      
   data = jQuery( data );
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jukums' comment led me to try turning off ColdFusion debug output and then .html() worked for me in IE8. To force debug output off:

```
<cfsetting showdebugoutput="No">
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was so easy like change the jquery version. I was using jquery-1.3.2 and I was add this line

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
```

instead jquery-1.3.2 import.
Without changing anything in my source code, the .prepend function works perfectly in IE, FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found that the simplest solution was to use the `replaceWith()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I had a issue on IE using this:

```
$('#valor_total').html(valor_total);
```

where `id` had the same name as the variable passed as a parameter.  Changing the id worked well:

```
$('#div_valor_total').html(valor_total);
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, I could only get it to work by placing my select in a placeholder div, and then write via .html(); the whole statement to that div. Works completely.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if you use a tagName prefix in your selector it is slower than just using the id.

In your case just use `$("#edit-state").append(options)`

Answer (score 0):

Check that any JavaScript in the returned data is syntactically correct.

I had a JSON options object that had a trailing comma, and that was enough for IE to refuse to run it.

Answer (score 0):

On my case too the returned data should be syntactically correct.
I had some unmatched tags like , unclosed tags

or .. etc

check if all data is correct

if this is an ajax request, then quick way for debug would be to add a text area outside the area you populate and populate the text area with the returned data. then check that data for inconsistencies.  Jquery.html is working fine with IE

Answer (score 0):

In IE8 go to **tools**-> **internet options**-> then select the **advanced** tab.  Then click **reset** to reset all internet explorer settings.

I thought I had a problem with my code but the problem was IE8.  This worked a treat.

Good luck and hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 1.4.2? There's an issue with the `cleanData` method using invalid cache entries in IE. The bug and corresponding fix can be found [here](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/6444). This affects calls to `.html()`

Comment: any ideas how to work around this without upgrading to a new jQuery version?

Comment: Yup. Just modify the jQuery library to include the line I posted there.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered an same problem when html does not work in IE.

I believe it does not work if you have invalid html

Example:

For my case i am using an div without a close tag. So invalid html might be a culprit for IE

Answer (score 0):

As the solution is not mentioned here:
I just had the same problem in IE8 when activating compatibility mode. The solution was to pass in a jQuery object to the .html() function like this:

```js
$("select#edit-state").html($(options));
```

This was not a problem if the options were a jQuery object and also built as one. But in the above example, this should do the trick - at least for me it did.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've had to change the selector that was a `<figure>` tag. This is what I had:

HTML:

```
<figure id="imagen">...</figure>
```

JS (**does not work**):

```
$("#imagen").html(res);
```

And I had to replace with:

HTML:

```
<div id="imagen">...</div>
```

JS (**it works!**):

```
$("#imagen").html(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the way I was commenting out my javascript in the data being loaded.

```
// Works fine

/* Works fine */

<!-- This causes a syntax error in IE -->
```

I've never had any problems commenting out like that in IE before, only when using  ajax to load it into an existing page. No problem with th eother browsers either.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the no cache attribute to the controller fixed this for me.

Copied from this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12948321/1389589