# jquery not working in IE but fine in FF

Tags: jquery

This works perfectly in FF and Safari but not in IE...
Here is the function:

```
  function my_totals(){
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "ajax.php",
    data: "action=my_items",
    success: function(data){
      $("#usage").html(data);
     }
 });
}
```

Comment: what/where is my_totals being called from?

Comment: Yes, I did. I can't believe I forgot to add the error... long day.
I get '$' is undefined.

my_totals() is being called from an <input> button onclick.

Comment: It seems that there is a problem when you import the jquery.js. Perhaps an unclosed tag? (http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/b79cf59b7d40f8f0)

Answer (score 0):

You can look [here](http://www.ventanazul.com/webzine/articles/stupid-internet-explorer)

Karl Swedberg said:

> one possibility is that you're trying to inject invalid markup with .html(). I noticed this causing problems with a plugin I wrote. For example, inserting something like `<div>`this is a div with no closing div tag caused IE to churn

Also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412734/jquery-html-attribute-not-working-in-ie/412758#412758)

I hope it helps you...