# Why does IE not add <option> to my dropDown?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm running this [sample script](http://jsfiddle.net/KsV2F/2/) with IE:

```
var $select = $('#select');
var $button = $('#button');

$button.click(function() {
    var $option = $('<option />');
    $option.text('hello');
    $option.appendTo($select);
});

var $tabs = $('#tabs');
$tabs.tabs();
```

It's pretty straight forward: when clicking on the button, an `option` should be added to my dropdown. This works great - the basic fct in IE either.

My problem:
just "open" the dropDown, and "close" it again. Now switch to tab "button" and hit the button. Now switch to tab "select" - a new `option` should be available.
This works great on every browser except IE ... (sometimes IE messes up after several tab-switches)

How can I fix my script?

Comment: Are you saying it doesn't work at all, or it doesn't work after several tab switches?

Comment: sometimes not working at all, sometimes after some switches ... please try out my fully working example to see how your IE behaves :)

Comment: you can try that on jsfiddle on your own :) ... but i'll try that in a sec

Comment: Oops removed my comment. Indeed, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a much simpler, and more cross-browser friendly, way to add options to select boxes than adding `option` DOM elements ([live example](http://jsbin.com/ipenes)):

```
$button.click(function() {
    var option = new Option('hello');
    $select[0].options.add(option);
});
```

Perhaps that would work more reliably for you. (Note that it's `add`, **not** `push`. The `options` object on `select` elements isn't really an array.)

Instead of `options.add` you can also do:

```
$button.click(function() {
    var options = $select[0].options,
        option  = new Option('hello');
    options[options.length] = option;
});
```

...which also adds to the end, in an array-like way. But `add` is reliable cross-browser.

Comment: just to give you a more accurate direction: the problem does not occur when working on the same div. somehow it is connected to `select` in hidden div and previously "opened" and "closed". if i just leave the select untouched and switch tab and add an `option` it just works perfectly!

Comment: yes, until now :) ... thanks a lot! (the real idea behind my cmt was not a wrong answer, rather a more accurate solution to my problem - is it a jquery issue? what am i doing wrong? is it ie? ... besides your magically overall solution, it would be nice to get the real problem here)