# Appending Select Option From Input (IE error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a select option to a form from an input field. I have it working fine in all browsers except IE which doesn't seem to to add the option.  Help is appreciated!

HTML

```
<select name="folder" id="folder" class="select Slectbox">
</select>

<label for="addfolder">Add Folder</label>
<input type="text" class="input-add-list" placeholder="new folder name" />
<button onClick="return false;" class="spr btn">Add</button>
```

JQUERY

```
<script>
$('.spr').on('click',function(){
    if($('.input-add-list').val().trim()!=='')
    {
        $('.SlectBox').append('<option value="'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'">'+$('.input-add-list').val().trim()+'</option>');
        $("select option:last").attr("selected","selected");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Add a JSFiddle so people can help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607633/why-does-ie-not-add-option-to-my-dropdown

Comment: also this is my first ever post so apologies if formatting / tone is wrong

Comment: Like @Riddel said, I think it's a duplicate, try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7607724/5444802

Comment: Thanks, i did check that. If you try the example, it doesnt work!

Comment: I sorted it!  Using the duplicate post (sorry - it did work, though I altered it to add from an input). Thanks for the help