# How to add session variable in ASP.Net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej9Ap.png)

**I am just using this code
is it enough for session? Though its not working
after logout when i click back it display me the same result**

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19315812/6522459

Comment: Thank you so much.
ALLAH BLESS YOU