# MVC 5 App - Implement No Client Page Caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

I want to prevent any client page in my MVC 5 application from being cached. My _Layout.cshtml page looks as follows. Notice the code in the head tag. Is this enough (and is it correct) to prevent caching on any page in my app? Or do I need to also add code on every page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta http-equiv="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache">


    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img class="visible-lg visible-md" src="~/Images/WebBirderFatbirder.png" title="WebBirder">
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bodyContentDiv" class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <br/>
            <br />
            <br />
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC how to disable automatic caching option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948156/asp-net-mvc-how-to-disable-automatic-caching-option)

Comment: the above url or this one has 2 valid options.  one for front and back end 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute.  personally I prefer the data annotation option on the controller