# Back button click not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I just found that when I click browser back button on any ASP .NET MVC page the html is correct but it is not loading the selected values from the dropdown on the page. And only if you click F5 it will be updated only.

How it can be resolved for ASP .NET MVC 5?

Thank for any clue...

Comment: Post you code please

Comment: Sounds like caching issue.  Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948156/asp-net-mvc-how-to-disable-automatic-caching-option) to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it sounds like a caching issue. Putting something like this in should reset the configurations properly.

```
[OutputCache(NoStore=true, Duration=0)]
public ActionResult Register()
{

}
```