# Entity Framework seems to be caching data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My issue is that when I write a basic EF query to get data from the database, it retrieves the data fine, but when I change the data in the SQL Server database and reload the query, I get the same dataset back, instead of the new data. And it takes a while for the data to be the amended information.

```
var mm = o.GetContent(page, title);
```

The above query, for example, would bring back

```
mm.Body = "Test";
```

Then if I change `Body` within the SQL Server database to `Test1` and reload the query, it doesn't bring back `Test1`.

```
public String GetContent(String page, String title)
{
    var o = new DataContext();

    var mm = o.GetContent(page, title);

    return HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(mm.Body);
}

public class DataContext
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext Da = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public Content GetContent(String page, String title)
    {
        return Da.Content.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Page == page && c.Title == title);
    }   
}
```

I've visited a number of SO posts:

[Prevent Caching in ASP.NET MVC for specific actions using an attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute)

[ASP.NET MVC how to disable automatic caching option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948156/asp-net-mvc-how-to-disable-automatic-caching-option)

Comment: Could you show how you query is built? Full LINQ statement?

Comment: Hi Kamo, I have edited my question.

Comment: When querying again are you creating a new instance of you `ef context`, if you're not it's ef that is querying it's cache

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your DbContext instance is static:

```
private static ApplicationDbContext Da = new ApplicationDbContext();
```

Hence per AppDomain, so it lives until you recycle the application pool. The `DbContext` holds a cache of items it's seen before, until you [call the `Refresh()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20270736/266143).

But don't do that. Don't make it static. Use Entity Framework as a Unit of Work, as narrowly-scoped as possible. Create one instance per request.

Comment: Like the clarity of your statement 'Create one instance per request.'