# $http.get method doesn't work when calling second time

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

On first load to detail page works fine. But if I go to different page and come back to the detail page $http.get doesn't get new data(it doesn't hit the MVC controller). It shows the same result as in previous time.

------------Detail Page------------------------

`<div ng-controller="mycontroller" ng-init="loadPage()"></div>`

-----------Controller------------------

```
myapp.controller("mycontroller", ["$scope", function($scope){
    $scope.loadPage= function(){
       $http.get("url").success(function(data){
          $scope.data = data;
}}}]);
```

Comment: Any chance you set up a cache in your app settings ?

Comment: Thanks. It worked by disabling cache. I found a solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948156/asp-net-mvc-how-to-disable-automatic-caching-option

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Work-around to avoid `$digest already in progress` error.

Add

`if (!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply();
 }`

in your function

Comment: ... and it will throw nice "$digest already in progress" error.

Comment: True... I used it and I got the $digest error, but it still worked. I was told to use `$timeout()` which apparently should have an implicit `$scope.apply()` at the end, but that didn't work.