# disable auto routing to mobile version mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I developed asp.net mvc application using visual studio 2015 default asp.net mvc application. Now I want to disable auto redirecting to the mobile version. please help me to fix this issue

Comment: 1) If you have file with extensions .mobi please try removing it and check,
2) Check for media queries in css to render the proper view,
3) Check the route information in RouteConfig.cs

Please elaborate the scenario for more help

Comment: [check it] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948156/asp-net-mvc-how-to-disable-automatic-caching-option)