# href generated in javascript doesnt hit mvc action in second time

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I generate html like this in javascript
as you can see theres an a tag in html

when I click first time in link it hit the action, but sometimes (can say 90% of cases) second click doesnt hit the action unless I clear the firefox or chrome cache
what's going here? and how can I solve this problem?

```
$.each(response, function (index, item) {
                            htmlcontent = "<div class=''>" +
                                "<a target='_blank' href='/Stat/" + item.Code + "/" + item.RId + "'>" +
                                "<img class=''  src='/Images/" + item.ImageId + "'/>" +
                                "</a>" +
                                "</div>";
                            $('.div_SecondCol').eq(index).html(htmlcontent);
                        });
```

and this is action

```
 // GET: Stat/{code}/{RId}
public ActionResult AdsStat(string Code, int? RId)
        {

            try
            {
                #region Load Data
                  //some code
                #endregion
                #region Insert Data
                  //some code
                #endregion

                return RedirectPermanent(externalUrl);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

when I add a random number at the end of href it works! but I need to know what's going here?

```
var randnum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1);
"<a target='_blank' href='/Stat/" + item.Code + "/" + item.RId + "?rnum=" + randnum + "'>" +
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in console on second click? And are sure that Item is not null after redirect from first click?

Comment: no there's no error, and in second click it goes to external href without hitting the action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its because HTTP Permanent Redirects `301` is cached by default. So browser opens cached page with **identical** URL, instead of making trip on server. Thats why its working, when you add random url parameter.

More about caching on [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching)

If you want to disable caching in general or disable caching on specific action. I would suggest to try solution from [Prevent Caching in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011780/prevent-caching-in-asp-net-mvc-for-specific-actions-using-an-attribute) or [ASP.NET MVC how to disable automatic caching option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948156/asp-net-mvc-how-to-disable-automatic-caching-option)

Comment: I think this is answer, I need to learn more about Permanent Redirects and Caching, thanks