# Script not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following script where I calculate a price based on user input radio buttons and output it into a section of html.  The script is not working in internet explorer properly.  It works in FF, Chrome, etc.  The script is supposed to take an input from a radio button and then based on the input it will output a different price.  It is not outputting a price in IE.

```
var newprice = "";        

function CalcPrice(){
    // I take the input from the radio buttons here 
    var goals = $("#menu input[type='radio']:checked").val();

    if (goals=="Weight Loss"){
        newprice="45";
    } else {
        newprice="55";
    }

    $('.pricetotal').html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));
}
```

HTML

```
<form class= "meal-table" id="meal-radio" onsubmit="return false">
          <fieldset id="menu">
         <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="menu" value="Weight Loss" />
         <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="menu" value= "Performance"/>
          </fieldset>
    <div>
      <div class="meal-plan-btn">
        <button id="mealbtn" onclick="CalcPrice()">Add To Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
 </form>
```

// this is where the price will be injected

```
          <div class="pricebox" id="priceboxmobile">
            <div class="pricetotal" >
              <span ></span>
            </div></div>
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412734/jquery-html-attribute-not-working-in-ie

Comment: Hit F12 to open the Developer Tools. Go to the Console tab. Is there a script error? Which IE version?

Comment: As @EricLaw noted above, please clarify what version of IE you are using. Some older versions may not support some common javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately I am unable to test in IE.  For some reason it wont let me download IE 9 on my computer because i have windows 10.  I have had a few complaints about this from customers so trying to fix it.  As a side note.... Any ideas how to test in older IE versions?

Comment: Try `$('.pricetotal span').html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));` That's what you want anyway, otherwise your span will be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing this line

```
 $('.pricetotal').html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));
```

To:

```
 $('.pricetotal').empty().html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));
```

Seems to work, anyone know why?

Comment: I cant accept my own answer, but this is the answer

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change

```
$('.pricetotal').html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));
```

to

```
$('.pricetotal span').html("$"+newprice.toFixed(2));
```

it will be fixed.

IE is a stickler for those kind of things.
But in this case it's what you want anyway, otherwise your `span` will be removed.
Alternatively, remove the `span` altogether..