# jquery ajax won't work

Tags: jquery, ajax

hey, i'm trying to change the html of a div after an ajax request, the ajax request works. the data is correct but the selector can't seems to find the div

here's the code

```
$(".home .up_0").click(function(){
  $.post("includes/vote.php",   
        {
         truc : $(this).attr("id")
        },
       function(data){ 
        if(data=='fail') 
        {
          alert("Error.");
        }
        else
        {
          $(this).parents('.home').find('.score_neutre').html(data);
        }
       }
  );
});
```

Comment: We'll need to see some of your HTML code to figure out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the corresponding HTML code?

Comment: `this` probably doesn't exist in the callback function. There surely is a workaround for this in JQuery but I don't know what it's called.

Comment: I think Pekka is headed in the right direction. I suggest possibly capturing `this` and storing it for use later.

Comment: Also important, what browser are you using? .html() has problems under certain browsers. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably because `this` isn't what you expect within the inner function. You'll need to add a variable to store the reference:

```
$(".home .up_0").click(function(){
  var this_obj = $(this);
  $.post("includes/vote.php",   
        {
         truc : $(this).attr("id")
        },
       function(data){ 
        if(data=='fail') 
        {
          alert("Error.");
        }
        else
        {
          this_obj.parents('.home').find('.score_neutre').html(data);
        }
       }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `this` is not pointing to what you think it is.

Do this:

```
$(".home .up_0").click(function(){
  var $this = $(this); // Cache the current `this` as a jQuery wrapped DOM element
  $.post("includes/vote.php",
       { truc : $(this).attr("id") },
       function(data){ 
          if(data=='fail') {
              alert("Error.");
          } else {
              // Reference the cached variable `$this`
              $this.parents('.home').find('.score_neutre').html(data);
          }
       });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do with `this` not representing the `$(".home .up_0")` element since it's inside the `function(data){}` success function?

Try adding a dummy div, id="Test" and inside the success function use:

```
£('#Test').html(data);
```

This will tell you if it's working.  If it is you'll need to use a var to store what `this` represents.