# asp:DropDownList fill options by javascript not using clientSideId

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to fill options in asp:DropDownList using javascript but without getElementById. I would rather like selector which uses class.

Thanks for any help
bye

Comment: why do you mean by getElementby ID, I think we need to use find the element in javascript to fill the dropdownlist  ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery) to fill dropdown values using jQuery.