# Create select list with simplejson dump

Tags: ajax, json, google-app-engine

Based on "Using AJAX to Enable Client RPC Requests [1](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc) " article I've created a list.

By using: 
`self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(result_list))`
I can read the result_list using `<input id="result_list" type="text" value="" />`

Help requested: How to convert the "result_list" into HTML Select List?

Answer (score 0):

loop over the values in the list and create a select tag.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: That's correct. The problem is that the self.response.out.write(simplejson.dumps(result_list)) is showing up only in <input id="result_list" type="text" value="" /> but does not show up as a list

Answer (score 0):

The doc showing "Using AJAX to Enable Client RPC Requests" dates from 2008. Today we use jquery to create browser independant javascript clients using ajax / json. 
Here is a code snippet to add options: [How do I add options to a DropDownList using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)