# jquery/css change list into dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, list, drop-down-menu

Here is the code:

```
<div id="TBRefineHead">
<h3>By&nbsp;Location</h3>
<ul>
<li><span class="refineDet"><a href="Search.aspx?ModuleID=643&amp;keywords=test&amp;multiSite=False&amp;Tax=41">Australia wide&nbsp;(1)</a></span></li>
<li><span class="refineDet"><a href="Search.aspx?    ModuleID=643&amp;keywords=test&amp;multiSite=False&amp;Tax=27">Location&nbsp;(1)</a></span></li>
</ul>
<h3>By&nbsp;Subject Matter</h3>
<ul>
<li><span class="refineDet"><a href="Search.aspx?ModuleID=643&amp;keywords=test&amp;multiSite=False&amp;Tax=17">Air Quality&nbsp;(1)</a></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make them into two drop-down select lists?

```
<select>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
<option></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS. Have a look at [this](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu) tutorial for making dropdown menus.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the help, what about i want to make it look like the dropdown selected look and feel: 

    <select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    </select>

Comment: Well... I'd say use the select tags? Are you using this on a form or just for navigation? I don't think there is an easy way to give that sort of functionality to a <ul> without javascript, and even if the form was recreated, <select> tags are rendered using native system controls, so their style vary from OS to OS.

Comment: hi Kevin9794, i want to use it as a dropdown list but not nav. Basically is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bmgonzal/SkGDq/7/ but it wasn't work...

Comment: I suggest you use <select>. There are jQuery plugins to stylise <select> items. Have a look here: http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: As for using <ul>, you could have a look here http://v2.easy-designs.net/articles/replaceSelect/

Comment: And for a kind of inbetweenish method, implementing both, check this article on the always handy css-tricks.com: http://css-tricks.com/convert-menu-to-dropdown/

Answer (score 0):

refer to this, can get some idea from it
[How do I add options to a DropDownList using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)