# How to add options into jquery multi-select-filter drop down using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have to add options into my dropdown with ajax call in jquery's multiselect-filter dropdown.

this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaikratsingh/4t6jLwa9/)

I do not have to show any data in dropdown until user type something in filter. The time user type anything in filter box, one ajax call will be made and dropdown will be populated. I am fine with ajax call but how to add new options into dropdown.

I have tried all below options to add options into my dropdown.

1) From here I got the idea [source](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/refresh.htm). This is going in an infinite loop.

```
var el = $("#id").multiselect();

$("#id").multiselect().multiselectfilter({
    filter: function(event, matches){           

        var v = "val", opt = $('<option />', {
            value: v,
            text: v
        });
        opt.appendTo( el );    
        el.multiselect('refresh');
     }
});
```

2) From here I got the idea [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery)

```
var myOptions = {
    val1 : 'text1',
    val2 : 'text2'
};
var mySelect = $('#mySelect');
$.each(myOptions, function(val, text) {
    mySelect.append(
        $('<option></option>').val(val).html(text)
    );
});
```

and few more with little changes here and there. Please suggest.

**EDIT**

Or is there any way to hide all options from the dropdown and show them only when filter matches with any of them!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$('<option />', {
            value: "test",
            text: "test"
        }).appendTo("#test");
$("#test").multiselect('refresh');
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qstuo306/)

You can move it in ajax call on success and populate it there with the result you get.

Comment: Thanks @Alek.. let me try.

Comment: Actually.. I have to addthe entry at the time of filtering not at onLoad of the page.

Comment: Dunno why you want to do something like that.. You can simple populate your multiselect on success of ajax call. Can't find a reason to append while filtering.

Comment: Take a look here if you try to append inside filter http://jsfiddle.net/qstuo306/36/

Comment: I have around 12K rows which is populated in this dropdown. So I do not want to show all that but to show them when user filter something and I think we should not use ajax on full page load. On first time we already have our processors...right!!!... please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I tried this approach... its going in infinite loop :(

Comment: Then you don't show anything and make an ajax call each time user types something and populate on success.

Comment: thats what I am not able to do it Alek and asking help for the same :)

Comment: Without see whole code is difficult to say. The general idea is to follow what i suggest.