# How to replace dropdown menu options with your own options using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu: Code. The options of "code" come from the database and the dropdown is populated. I have a textbox: Name. For certain values populated in Name (again from database), I want to replace the dropdown menu options with my own set of options, essentially overwriting the ones that are already there. Is there a way to do this?

My Code:
HTML:

```
 <div>
    <table>
    <tbody><tr><td><label>Code</label></td><td>
    <select class="codeSelection"></select></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>                            
</div>

<div>
 <table>
  <tbody><tr><td><label>Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="nameInput"></td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>                            
</div>
```

Code that I tried so far: (followed [How do I add options to a DropDownList using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery))

```
$('.nameInput').html("");
$('.nameInput').val(data[0].codeValue);
    if ($('.nameInput').val() =="Smith")
            {
                var myOptions = {
                    val1 : "Tom",
                    val2 : "John"
                            };
                    $.each(myOptions, function(val, text){
                    $('.codeSelection').append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
                            });
            }
```

This still gives me the old dropdown and just displays the values "Tom" and "John" as text.

Comment: What is this: `new Option(text,val)`? That doesn't look like JavaScript to me--unless there's code you aren't showing. Follow the code example as shown in your linked question.

Comment: @dave please see the updated code. followed the accepted answer in the linked question.

Comment: are you executing this in the document.ready?

Comment: @dave: [`option()` constructor (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option), [`Option()` object (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dd757810(v=vs.85).aspx). In short: it's perfectly valid JavaScript (though I don't know which version of ECMAScript or JavaScript first introduced it).

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks, you learn something new every day. [It appears to have been created with HTML5](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/forms.html#dom-option)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will read your text box value and loop thru the options inside the dropdown and update as needed. Make changes as needed.

```
  var txtVal=$("#nameInput").val();

  $("#codeSelection option").each(function() {
    var _item=$(this);  
    console.log(_item.val());
    if(_item.val()===txtVal)
     {
         //_item is the one you want. Make the changes as needed.
         // Here i am updating the value and text.
         _item.val("newValue").text("NewName");
     }
   });
```

Working sample :  http://jsbin.com/zexapizabe/2/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clear your options before appending:

```
$('.codeSelection option').remove();
```

There's a runnable snippet below if you want to see it in action. As soon as you click off the name, the dropdown options will change.

```js
$('.nameInput').on("blur", function() {

   if ($('.nameInput').val() =="Smith") {
  var myOptions = {
   val1 : "Tom",
   val2 : "John"
  };
  
  $('.codeSelection option').remove();
  $.each(myOptions, function(val, text){
   $('.codeSelection').append($('<option></option>').val(val).html(text));
  });
 }
});

$(function() {
    $(".nameInput").get(0).focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div>
    <table>
    <tbody><tr><td><label>Code</label></td><td>
    <select class="codeSelection">
      <option>Name One</option>  
    </select></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>                            
</div>

<div>
 <table>
  <tbody><tr><td><label>Name</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="nameInput" value="Smith"></td></tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>                            
</div>
```

Comment: `.remove()` is removing the options but I'm not able to append my options. I still have the option value appearing as a text on the form.

Comment: I'm confused. Is my snippet working as you would like it to? I may be misunderstanding your question.

Comment: Yes the code snippet is running perfectly. But when I use it my code, it fails. The only difference seems to be that Im loading my dropdown menu from the database when the page is created. After I use `.remove()` the options are removed but the new options are not being added to the dropdown. I cant seem to get around this.