# How to append php associative array to html using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

i want to retrive this json in my select box this is my controller code and

```
public function getDistrictById()
        {
                $StateId=$this->input->post('StateId');
                $District=$this->Main_model->getDistrictListByStateId($StateId);
                //echo json_encode($District);
                foreach($District as $d)
                {

                     $rows[]=array("id"=>$d->DistrictId,"name"=>$d->DistrictName);
                }
                print json_encode($rows);

        }
```

here is my jquery/ajax code

```
<script>
function getDistrict()
 {
        var StateId=$('#state option:selected').val();
        $.ajax({
                           url:'<?php echo base_url()?>Home/getDistrictById',
                           type: 'POST',
                          dataType:"json",
                           data: {StateId:StateId},
                           success: function(response){
                            // $('#District').html(response); 
                            console.log(response);
                           },

                           error: function(){
                               alert("Fail");
                           }
                       });
 }
</script>
```

the console.log(response); give me the exact output but i am not sure how to appen this in to a select box. i have already try [How do I add options to a DropDownList using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery) and many more plz help...

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this in success callback

```
    <script>  
    function getDistrict()
                            {
                                var StateId = $('#state option:selected').val();
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: '<?php echo base_url()?>Home/getDistrictById',
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    dataType: "json",
                                    data: {StateId: StateId},
                                    success: function (response) {
                                       $("#district").empty();  // clear previous options
                                        for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++)
                                        {
                                            $("#district").append("<option value='" + response[i].id + "'>" + response[i].name + "</option>");
                                        }
                                    },
                                    error: function () {
                                        alert("Fail");
                                    }
                                });
                            }
       </script>
```

Comment: no its not working for me when i add this line it show error  getDistrict not defined. i want to populate all the releated district in selectbox

Comment: Sorry, my mistake your response will get id and name attribute not DistrictId and DistrictName. I have update my answer check now.
Post your console result if its still not work

Comment: i did the following thing but it is not populating the related district   <select name="district" id="district">
                   
                   
                </select>

Comment: you use select id district (lowercase). change same in my code. use #district not #District

Comment: yes i change it already but it does not populating anything. i am new to json can you tell me  foreach($District as $d)
                {

                     $rows[]=array("id"=>$d->DistrictId,"name"=>$d->DistrictName);
                }
                print json_encode($rows);                                                            above code give me right result. if you have any idea about that i am waiting for your response.

Comment: Are you getting a single district or an array of districts?

Comment: array of district when i print the response in to console it show me  [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
id
:
"4"
name
:
"Anantapur"
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
id
:
"5"
name
:
"Chittoor"
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
id
:
"6"
name
:
"Cuddapah"
__proto__
:
Object
3
:
Object
id
:
"7"
name
:
"East Godavari"
__proto__
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
12
:
Object
length
:
13

Comment: check now i have change my answer

Comment: $("#district").append("<option value='" + response[i].id + "'>" + response[i].name + "</option>") code is working for me it return response but  i have to  change <select id="district></select> to <div id="district"></div>

Comment: don't you need select box (Dropdown) with options ?

Comment: i need but it not populating anything but when i change it to div it populates do you have any idea what is wrong

Comment: anyway thank you so much for your kind help if you have any new  suggesting about this plz comment.

Comment: Its strange it should work you may have some typo . Change  jquery selecter like this $("select#district") instead of $("#district");

Comment: try to console your select like this console.log($("#district")); and check  what it print in console. Its should return your tag not an empty array []

Comment: thanks it work perfectly right now i am facing an problem when i first select state delhi it shows the delhi district but after this when i select other state it append the district next to the option like first delhi option and then other state oprion how to resolve this

Comment: you need to use $("#district").empty();  in success callback before for loop start. It will remove previous options from list and append new one