# how to get the values list from Spring MVC Controller to jsp page on selecting an option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

In a jsp page there will 3 drop downs on clicking one drop down and selecting a value,another drop down will open and on clicking that another drop down and selecting a value,one more drop down will open where there will be list of values from Spring MVC Controller.So how to do this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#company').change(function() {
           var e = document.getElementById('company');
           var value1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
           alert(value1);
           $.ajax({
               type : 'GET',
               url : 'companynames',
               data : {
                   company : value1
               },
               success : function(response) {
                   getcompNames(response);
              }
           });
       });
   });

   function getCompNames(response) {
       $('#corpotrips option').remove();

       var options = '';
       $.each(response, function(index,item) {
           options += '<option value="' +item+ '">' + item + '<option>';
           $('#corpotrips').html(options);
       })
   }

   $(function() {
        $('.multiselect').multiselect();
    });
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#individual").hide();
      $("#corporate").hide();
      $("#companies").hide();
      $("#deadbills").hide();
        $('#Type').on('change', function() {

          if ( this.value == 'Individual')
          {

            $("#individual").show();
            $("#corporate").hide();
            $("#companies").hide();
            $("#deadbills").hide();

          }
          else if(this.value == 'Corporate')
          {

            $("#individual").hide();
            $("#corporate").hide();
            $("#companies").show();
            $("#deadbills").hide();
          }
          else if(this.value == 'DeadBills')
              {

              $("#individual").hide();
              $("#corporate").hide();
              $("#companies").hide();
              $("#deadbills").show();
              }

          else {

              $("#individual").hide();
              $("#corporate").hide();
              $("#companies").hide();
              $("#deadbills").hide();
          }
        });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<form action="Bills" method="post">

        <table><tr>
        <td><select id='Type' name = "tripType">
        <option value="">select</option>
<option value="Individual">Individual</option>
<option value="Corporate">Corporate</option>
<option value="DeadBills">DeadBills</option>
</select></td>
<td><div id='individual'>
 <select id="multiple-checkboxes" multiple="multiple" name="tripNumber">

        <c:forEach var="bills" items="${individualTrips}">
    <option value="${bills.tripNumber}">${bills.tripNumber}</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div></td>
<td><div id='companies'>
 <select id='company' name="companyName">
     <option>Select Company</option>
        <c:forEach var="bills" items="${corporateTrips}">

    <option value="${bills.companyName}">${bills.companyName}</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div></td>
<td><div id='corporate'>
 <select id='corpotrips' class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="tripNumber">

    </select>
</div></td>
<td><div id='deadbills'>
 <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="tripNumber">

        <c:forEach var="bills" items="${deadbillTrips}">
    <option value="${bills.tripNumber}">${bills.tripNumber}</option>
      </c:forEach>
    </select>
</div></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/companynames", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<TripSheet> getEnvironmentNames(HttpServletRequest request,
               HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam String company) {
        List<TripSheet> myList = this.tripSheetService.getCompanyByName(company);
         return myList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use an ajax call on clicking the second dropdown item. you can check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/) example for calling and ajax request for spring mvc. after that in your ajax success method you can use jquery to add variable to dropdown list.[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317095/how-do-i-add-options-to-a-dropdownlist-using-jquery) is an example for adding options into dropdown menu.